# Prove that the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n) + 1$, $ n\ge1 $, $ n\ne4 $ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math, irreducible-polynomials

I try to solve this problem. I seems to come close to the end but I can't get the conclusion. Can someone help me complete my proof. Thanks

> > Show that the polynomial $h(x) = (x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n) + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$ for all $n\ge1$ and $ n\ne4$.

Suppose $h(x) = f(x) g(x)$, then we must have $f(i)g(i) = 1$ for all $i = 1,2,...n$. So both $f(i)$ and $g(i)$ are $1$ or $-1$. In either case, $m(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ has degree smaller than $n$ and have $n$ different roots ($1,2,...,n$). So we must have $m(x) = 0$. Then $h(x) = f(x)^{2}$. So $n$ must be even. Let $n = 2k$. Because $f(x)$ has degree $k$, there are $k$ values from $\{1,2,...,2k\}$ at which $f(x)$ is $1$ and $k$ values at which $f(x)$ is $-1$.

This is where I got stuck. Hope some one can help me solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Great work. Now use the fact that $a-b | f(a) - f(b)$ for integer polynomials.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that property. Thanks so much. Got it clear right now...

Comment: In that case, please write up an answer, so that others can learn from it.

Comment: @CalvinLin: the solution is written up at many places. Helpful discussion is here: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2007;task=show_msg;msg=3779.0001.0001

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think you misunderstand. The intention is for this question to also have a complete answer attached to it, so that if someone stumbles upon this they do not have to click elsewhere to read it. Further, note that the link you provided deals with $f(x) = \ldots -1$, opposed to this which has $+1$.

Comment: No, it does apply as well to $+1$. The text discusses two questions , the first with $-1$, the second with $+1$. And why not to click "elsewhere", where you can learn more ?

Comment: There's no problem with clicking elsewhere, your link will remain in the comments for anyone who wants to see it.  There's also no problem with having an answer here.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, you are right. Anyway, we have many duplicates also inside of MSE. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029198/prove-that-px-x-1x-2-cdots-x-n-1-is-irreducible-over-mathbbz-f) now.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579971/proof-that-a-polynomial-is-irreducible-for-all-n-ne-4

Comment: Alternative strategy: show f(n-1/2)<0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AS @Calvin Lin suggest, I write down the complete answer here for someone who need.

From my deduction above, we must have $h(x) = f(x)^{2}$. And there are $k$ values from $\{1,2,...,2k\}$ at which $f(x)$ is $1$ and $k$ values at which $f(x)$ is $-1$.

Let $I$ is subset of $\{1,2,...,2k\}$ consists of elements at which $f(x)$ is $1$ and $J$ is subset of $\{1,2,...,2k\}$ consists elements at which $f(x)$ is $-1$. It's easy to see that if $n = 2$, then $h(x)$ is irreducible, and $n \neq 4$, so we just consider the case $n \ge 6$, which means that $k \ge 3$.

Suppose $I$ consists of $1$. $J$ has at least $3$ distinct elements greater than $1$, so there exists an elment $u$ in $J$ such that $u - 1 \ge 3$. But we must have $u - 1 | f(u) - f(1) = -2$, contradiction.

Comment: Why must there be k values from ${1,2...,2k}$ at which at which $f(x)$ is $1$ and $k$ values at which $f(x)$ is $-1$.

Comment: @user162089 suppose, for instance, there are at least $k+1$ distinct values at which $f(x)$ is $1$. Then in $\mathbb Q[x]$, $f(x)-1$ is divisible by (at least) $k+1$ distinct linear factors since $\mathbb Q$ is a field; but this is impossible because that would imply that $f(x)-1$, and hence $f(x)$, would have at least degree $k+1$.

Answer (score 4):

For $n\geq 7$ the irreducibility follows from following criterion of Pólya (see Polynomials by Prasolov).

> **(Pólya).** Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with integer coefficients and define $m=\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor$. Suppose that, for $n$ different integers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ we have $|f(a_i)|<2^{-m}m!$ and the numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are not roots of $f$. Then $f$ is irreducible.

Choose $a_i=i$ and for $n \geq 7$ the claim follows.

Comment: Ah! I started digging and found this. I seem to have upvoted this back in the day, so couldn't add another one :-(