# Prove that $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-n) + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \geq 1$, $n \neq 4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Prove that $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-n) + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \geq 1$, $n \neq 4$.

I do not clearly see how to solve this problem and what is so special about the integer $4$ here?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)+1=(x^2 - 5x + 5)^2$ is reducible for $n=4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That exception is included in the problem statement.

Comment: @Goos : this answers the question of the OP on *why* $n=4$ is special. user26857 also answered to this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okay.  Though I think that the OP is not asking why it factors for $n=4$, but rather a deeper reason for why the proof of the proposition that it is irreducible (whatever that proof is) fails when $n=4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That is not very deep at all.  If you read the answer on the linked duplicate question, you will see that the reason it fails is closer to the fact that $4 / 2 = 2$ is not larger than the difference $|1 - (-1)|$.

Comment: @Goos: Well, if you think this is deeper, then OK.